# Error while creating Hybrid Mobile Cordova application project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, mobile, hybrid

I have installed Apache Cordova and installed THyM plugin in Eclipse. When I try to create Hybrid Mobile Cordova application project in eclipse, it is throwing error "Cordova not found, please run npm install -g cordova in command line." Whereas I have already installed cordova. Please help.